# Some views with a CAGradientLayer don't render the gradient

Tags: ios, swift

I've been facing some difficulties trying to apply `CAGradientLayer`s on two items in a view controller: a `UIView` and a `UIButton`. On investigation, when the gradient is applied to both items, only the `UIButton` has the gradient on it whereas the `UIView` appears transparent.

My gradient is defined as such:

```swift
import UIKit

struct K {
    struct Design {
        static let upGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
            let layer = CAGradientLayer()
            layer.colors = [upBlue.cgColor, upPurple.cgColor]
            layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            return layer
        }()

        static let upBlue = UIColor(named: "UP Blue") ?? .systemBlue
        static let upPurple = UIColor(named: "UP Purple") ?? .systemPurple
    }
}
```

The function that applies the gradients (I used `insertSublayer`) is separated from the main View Controller file. Here's the code for that function:

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIButton {
    func applyButtonDesign(_ gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer) {
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func applyHeaderDesign(_ gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer) {
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

(**Note**: It appears that `addSublayer` doesn't work either.)

My UI is being created programmatically (without a Storyboard), and I'm fairly new to it. Here's the code for the view controller where the issue is happening:

```swift
import UIKit

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var headerView: UIView!
    var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    var focusImageView: UIImageView!
    var promptLabel: UILabel!
    var continueButton: UIButton!

    let headerGradientLayer = K.Design.upGradientLayer
    let buttonGradientLayer = K.Design.upGradientLayer

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

        let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // MARK: Header View
        headerView = UIView()
        headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        headerView.applyHeaderDesign(headerGradientLayer)
        view.addSubview(headerView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            headerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            headerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25)
        ])

        // MARK: Other items in ViewController

        // MARK: Continue Button
        continueButton = UIButton()
        continueButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        continueButton.applyButtonDesign(buttonGradientLayer)
        continueButton.setTitle("Let's go!", for: .normal)
        continueButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Metropolis Bold", size: 22.0)
        continueButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
        continueButton.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(continueButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(continueButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            continueButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: promptLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: K.Layout.someSpaceBetween),
            continueButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -K.Layout.someSpaceBetween),
            continueButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: K.Layout.someSpaceBetween),
            continueButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor),
            continueButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0)
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        headerGradientLayer.frame = headerView.bounds
        buttonGradientLayer.frame = continueButton.bounds
    }

    // MARK: - Functions
    @objc func continueButtonPressed() {
        let newViewController = NameViewController()
        newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        newViewController.hero.modalAnimationType = .slide(direction: .left)
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

When running on the Simulator, I get the below image that shows the issue. Notice that the gradient is not applied on the `UIView` but is on the `UIButton`.

[image: image of issue with gradient not applied on the UIView but is on the UIButton]

What's causing this issue to happen, and how can I resolve this? If there's a fundamental concept that needs to be learned to tackle this issue, do share as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `headerGradientLayer` and `buttonGradientLayer` refer to the same layer instance because `upGradientLayer` is a *stored* property, not a *computed* property (as I'm assuming you meant for it to be). Since they both refer to the same instance, when you call this:

```
continueButton.applyButtonDesign(buttonGradientLayer)
```

...which internally calls this:

```
self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

...it removes the gradient layer instance from its current view (your header view) and adds it to your button (because layers cannot have more than one superlayer). The result is that you only see the gradient on your button and not your header view.

I imagine you meant for `upGradientLayer` to be a computed property so that it returns a *new* layer instance every time it's called, like this:

```
static var upGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.colors = [upBlue.cgColor, upPurple.cgColor]
    layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    return layer
}
```